# Ads for external sites are broken for me

Tags: bug, site-ads

I saw this ad (code into 120 currencies):

[image]

And I was quite interested into seeing what it was, but clicking it did "nothing". Well, it doesn't do anything, but what it does do is the same end-result. It opens an `about:blank` tab before closing the newly opened tag.

If I skim-inspect source, I see the usual kind of stuff, but maybe there's something in the inline JavaScript code I missed:

```
<a target="_blank"
   href="https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsudjPIt357zvUAuuPc55xH6IgbYNLgfDMGElU7ySJ7UCTStM0LQIjjbFoc43Eh78gLQ_y1Gp1e4aSyuTZlQyUVpRGrjQExKHRUvMCzL9y3HuSx76hnZdBl5gUHOGyYIFgy1YIyhtwcO60AsT2mtjc3w3bbet8MAEoee2Smzvi5dWyfc6dKQlsca7x2IR8ScW8sIZjIRb2INnRmpnrh5rLUfEZWW1l9CqQQJZjCpJ9SHSCEdgFAl3Oj38ir-VpSXqUHGBWfc9q1F4ownxvXU8XAR_mh6WSJoyooSAAKdOEY4ejc6i4IE-pdvdJJ01u65K_t1gR_CkGsFAJhQAxQ&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzJTO7bVWpC1r&amp;urlfix=1&amp;nx=147&amp;ny=102&amp;dim=300x250&amp;adurl=http://adtrk.tw/tp/rj6_GyqU_z.K"
   onmousedown="var a=/^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp):|[^:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/i;var b=/^(https?:[^:?]+[/]pcs[/]click[^/]+?)(?:&amp;nx[^&amp;]+&amp;ny[^&amp;]+&amp;dim[^&amp;]+)?(&amp;adurl=.*)/;var c=event.currentTarget,d=c.querySelector(&quot;img[alt]&quot;);if(d){var e,f=c.href,g=&quot;&amp;nx=&quot;+ +Math.round(event.clientX-d.offsetLeft)+&quot;&amp;ny=&quot;+ +Math.round(event.clientY-d.offsetTop)+&quot;&amp;dim=&quot;+(+d.width+&quot;x&quot;+ +d.height),h=b.exec(f);e=h?h[1]+g+h[2]:f;a.test(e)&amp;&amp;(c.href=e)};">
    <img src="https://s0.2mdn.net/4991213/6-JPM_Ecommerce_300_x250-01.jpg"
         alt="Advertisement"
         width="300"
         height="250"
         border="0">
</a>
```

Interestingly enough, if I right click and choose to copy location URI, then I can paste that, and it will take me to the J.P Morgan site, so my gut is telling me it's the inline JavaScript code.

Environment Settings:

- OS: Linux Mint 19
- Browser: Firefox 67

Comment: Clearly, your code has no redeemable currency value, so you were redirected to `about:blank`. Sorry, bro.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure what you mean .. this is just the code from site source

Comment: I was attempting to make a joke. My lame sense of humor is one of my primary contributions to the Meta site.

Comment: @CodyGray haha /r/whoosh me right? xD

Comment: Isn't this a feature?

Comment: Yes, they said it was coming about 6-8 weeks ago.

Comment: @CodyGray *"your code has no redeemable currency value"*, describes my first (and only) PHP project perfectly.

Comment: @treyBake *"OS: Linux Mint 19"*, that's the problem right there.

Comment: Fast reading the inline js, they are sending the coordinates of your click (probably so they can know if you clicked "Apply now" or not), as query params. However this should not have any incidence on the click event itself. Are you sure you don't have an ad-blocker which is only set off on stackoverflow (and which would then block  *adclick.g.doubleclick.net* domain when you are out of SO?

Comment: @LogicalBranch hey now ... xD