# CraftCMS StackExchange ad broken

Tags: bug, site-ads, network-sites

There was a CraftCMS StackExchange ad on the right-hand side, which I was curious about so I clicked on it.

Instead of taking me to it, it simply opened an iframed version of the main site where the ad used to be:

[image]

My details:

```
Google Chrome   76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 76_132_win)
Revision        fd1acc410994a7a68ac25bc77513d443f3130860-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1035}
OS              Windows 10 OS Version 1803 (Build 17134.950)
```

In response to questions from [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene):

- No scripts installed. Adblock disabled on StackExchange sites.
- I was likely actively authenticated on other network sites.
- I didn't have an account on CraftCMS at the time.

Comment: @rene No special scripts. Ad blockers disabled on StackExchange. I likely did have a valid authenticated session since I sometimes browse the "Hot Network Questions" and I'm a member of a number of exchange sites. I had no account on CraftCMS when I clicked it, that's correct.

Comment: Maybe related/similar: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386038/ads-for-external-sites-are-broken-for-me

Comment: I guess this is one they don't plan to solve then?

Comment: I don't know. I've seen now enough bug reports where only a few users experience and report some bug with ads. They might not have enough context to understand the root cause. That is why I asked you to add some of the data points I could think of that could contribute. Allow for 6 to 8 weeks to have this solved ....

Comment: Ha @ 6-8 weeks.

Comment: that dupe was asked on Jul 17th, 2019 ....

Comment: @rene I... knew that. Brain fart.

Comment: How does afblock handle stuff if that gets loaded in an iframe? If you have disabled adblock for Stack Exchange does that mean adblock doesn't run for stuff inside iframes that are loaded from a Stack Exchange domain? I use adblock but I never really checked what disabling does. The theory is then that the iframe was loaded but not all of its content, for example: scripts that should have handled your click event

Comment: @rene That's a very good question. I'm not sure.